# Set images for different iphones and debug

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode7, xcasset

I am currently developing an ios app and the scope is limited to iPhones only and portrait mode only.

In each screen there are images, buttons, labels and textFields. The question here is, how do I render appropriate image for device from the Images.xcassets?

What I am doing now, written below -

1. From Sketch design application, exporting my images for 1x, 2x and 3x (Screens designed by a UI designer)
2. Adding them to Xcode project (drag and drop from finder to xcode)
3. Add new image set in Images.xcassets (naming it as "MyImages") and drag drop my images for 1x, 2x, 3x.
4. In the storyboard, on a viewcontroller, adding an ImageView
5. For the image view, selecting Image as "MyImages" from Attribute Inspector.

Once the above steps are complete, when I test the app on simulators starting from iphone4s, iphone5, iphone5s, iphone6 and so on.. (all the simulators available on Xcode 7.3), I don't see the appropriate image is being rendered.

*Is my approach correct?*

*Also, how do I debug a UI element on the screens? Like, how/where do I check for what image is rendered? Its size (W X H)?*

**Added Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Using Finder, go into the folder containing your image set.  Open Contents.json with a text editor and add that to your question.

Comment: ryantxr - how do I debug it on the simulator/device?

Comment: You should see the image in the Storyboard.

Comment: @Lohith Korupolu:  I am putting a 2nd answer to answer your recent screen shot as the question originally asked has already been answered. Hopefully the 2nd answer to address the query from you comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Lohith Korupolu:

The screen shot you provided is for **universal size** (iPhone/iPad). From the additional information provided in comments, this would lead to **issues with AutoLayout constraints** that would stop the image showing on screens of a smaller size than that shown in your StoryBoard.

**E.g.** I have replicated your issue on storyboard...

[image]

This results in the following in Simulator for iPhone 4s....

[image]

i.e. Text is there but **NO IMAGE**.

**REASON**:  The autoLayout Constraints set for the larger "Universal" Screen on any of two opposite sides would make the image invisible/ disappear when viewed on a smaller screen.

**SOLUTION**:

**1. Clear the Autolayout constraints for this selected Image in Storyboard. See next picture...**
[image]

**2. Add AutoLayout constraints as below x2 pictures. (Top constraint, Height + Width) (horizontally in container). Remembering to tick "Items of new constraints" for both.**

[image]
[image]

**3. Run Simulator for iPhone 4s... E.g.**

[image]

** The same situation is occuring with the other iPhone size simulator Runs. **

****** All Working ******

Comment: I tried a similar approach but used wCompact hRegular for all iPhones. And now, I need the image size to reduce according to the device. (I also have one more image beneath the one in screenshot.) For that, I started using equal widths with multiplier as 0.5. Doing so, the images  sizes are reducing but the vertical spacing between them is not reducing. How can I do that

Comment: @lohith-korupolu: Hi! ... this looks like a different question about autoLaout. Happy to chat separately about it. However I think its standard practice to 'Accept' an answer to a specific question if its been answered from a stack overflow perspective... ?

Comment: I accepted your answer, as it helped me fix the issue described in the question. But I still have autolayout issues. Can we once chat in yseterday's discussion window please?

Comment: Yes. Give me 20 mins and I'll be back at my desk to help

Answer (score 1):

They should all be 2x images for iPhones apart from the plus size iPhones which should be 3x. Is that not what you are seeing?

In terms of debugging / checking this - you can put place holder images in your assets with labels or different colour tints to distinguish them from each other and then replace them later with images that give the desired final appearance once you know that everything is working as expected.

Comment: so I don't need to add any 1x images at all?

Comment: Not sure about that, never tried leaving them out. You could easily find out by deleting one, but I suspect Xcode will complain.

Comment: the 2x images are same for iphone4s and iphone5+ as well. so, on iphone4s, the image appears big. How to handle this?

Comment: 1x 2x and 3x refer to the **resolution** of the images, not the size. The 2x are for retina screens, the 3x are for BIG retina screens and the 1x are for older, non retina devices like the original iPad mini. The **size** of your images on the screen is handled by the layout constraints, stack view settings, etc. You need to set up your auto layout to adapt nicely to different screen sizes. I suspect that you have some fixed size elements in your layout that need changing so that they shrink and grow with the available space.

Comment: Ah, got it. "I suspect that you have some fixed size elements in your layout that need changing so that they shrink and grow with the available space" - this is true. How do I do that? Sorry I am asking, I am new to ios native. I always did Hybrid apps using Cordova earlier. Could you please help me?

Comment: The solution depends on the specific layout of your app, but in my experience, stack views are the way to go. If you're not familiar with them then there is a nice little tutorial here https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views alternatively, post an image of your layout and I'll see if I can suggest anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113597/discussion-between-lohith-korupolu-and-chris).

Comment: I sent you a screenshot in the chat discussion

Answer (score 1):

Using 2x images for iPhones approach works fine, however, there is another more straight forward way without having to resort to multiple image files for 1x, 2x, 3x in Xcode, by use of good large quality PDF (vector).

**1. Create a Large PDF of the image/Graphic image you want to use**

**2. Import it into 'Assets.xcassets' - drag and drop (Into Xcode)**

**3. Go to the utilities panel on the right for the 'Attributes Inspector' (when the image is selected)**

See Screen shot (a)

[image]

[image]

Under '**Scale Factors**' the selection from 'Multiple' to '**Single Vector**'

Now when you got to 'StoryBoard' and add the image - Simply select the PDF's name.
**Xcode will automatically render it to correct size** etc at run time for you. All the work is done by Xcode.

**Exceptions:**
It does not work well with images for icons inside the TabBar or Navigation Bar Items.

**Note:**
Vector graphics are sharp and ideal for High Definition (HD), but although Xcode accepts the Image Asset as a vector from the PDF, it doesn't seem to keep the vector but converts it into an actual image with pixelation problems when zoomed in, from a HD perspective.

Comment: I can't see the pdf image under Images list, after I add it to Xcode.. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Add the image to Assetx.xcassets as you normally do for other images. Then wait a few seconds, click elsewhere and come back to them image again in Xcode (sometimes it takes a short while for Xcode to save it). Then Back to Storyboard... Do you have an "Image" holder or a Button? that you are adding the image to? Either Case, when you select on the object concerned ---  Look at the attributes inspector where you select images - Drop down to find the PDF you just loaded into you "Assets".

Comment: If its not showing, can you provide a screen shot of your Xcode screen to get an idea of what is going on? Thanks

Comment: yea got it, I did what's shown in screenshots. Now what I don't understand is, should I set the width and height to the imageView am using? If I set so, I don't see any changes happening to the image when I view them on iphone4s and other simulators, am confused

Comment: scope of my app is to work in iphones (from 4s) and portrait mode. I have an image that should appear on the top and aligned horizontally at the  center of the screen. But this image should resize according to the device, this is what I am looking for.

Comment: Just did a simulation of my answer with a few dummy images in simulator from 6sPlus down to 4s and all works fine. It looks like you have something else going on in your project causing a problem. Possible solutions: (a) Do a dummy quick project to test out my answer (b) Have you check AutoConstraints? //// "image should resize according to the device, this is what I am looking for" = You have AutoConstraints - that may not be done correctly...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113618/discussion-between-lohith-korupolu-and-devim1).